# How to do nearest neighbor search more quickly?

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-query

I am currently using geopandas and scipy.spatial to do a nearest neighbor query. I have a data set of close to a million points and I need to find all of the closest points from another data set that has about 2,000 points. Right now I am making my tree like so

```
self.shop_tree = cKDTree(self.tree[['LONGITUDE', 'LATITUDE']].values)
```

and my query like so

```
dist, ind = self.shop_tree.query(self.pnts[['longitude', 'latitude']])
```

After I complete the query I need to also know the distance between each point, so would it be best to do this as a separate operation after, or is there a way to compute these simultaneously?

Comment: [Nearest neighbor analysis with large datasets](https://automating-gis-processes.github.io/site/notebooks/L3/nearest-neighbor-faster.html) with [sklearn.neighbors.BallTree](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.BallTree.html)